# How to set all properties of base class through derived class

Tags: c#, .net

```
public BaseClass
{
    prop abc;
    prop pqr;
    prop xyz;    
}

public DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   prop New1;
   prop New2;

  //constructor
  public DerivedClass(BaseClass baseObj,someMore params)
  {
      this.abc = baseObj.abc;
      this.pqr = baseObj.pqr;
      this.xyz = baseObj.xyz;
      /* I do not want to do this for each and every property as I have more than 40 properties */

  }
}
```

Here in above code How I can set all properties of derived class which are same in derived class as base class.

In my derived class
Can I do somethign of following type to achieve above thing without using **Automapper** or **Reflection**

```
public DerivedClass(BaseClass baseObj,someMore params):base(baseObj) //or something similar
{
}
```

Comment: automapper can help with something like that.

Comment: also, reflection can help with something like that

Comment: Why not delegate to the base class this responsibility? Why not add a constructor in the base class as well, that takes responsibility for all the properties and fields in that type?

Comment: However, if your question is really how to do the "all" part, without having to write out each statement, then yes, reflection in some form is an option.

Comment: Can Constructor Chainign help here ?

Comment: What is your `BaseClass` constructor?

Comment: Without using reflection, there's not really a way to make this simpler. C# just isn't wired that way. You can use T4 templates to generate the boilerplate code at compile time instead. Or make a "builder" type (but this still requires a lot of boilerplate). Or use a dictionary, rather than a class.

Comment: @spodger base class is Plain POCO no explicit constructor I wrote

Comment: So you've got 40 properties that you've got to set individually somewhere.

Comment: Yes @spodger I ahve to popualte all those properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getskypeforbusinessactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize the properties in your base class instead of the derived class (since both the parameter and the base classes share the same type of class).

To copy the properties, besides AutoMapper (which I find really slow) and reflection (which is hard to implement and maintain), an easy, very efficient way to do this is using the open source library Omu.ValueInjecter:

Install the library from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ValueInjecter/):

```
Install-Package ValueInjecter -Version 3.1.3
```

Then, use it in your constructor as follows:

```
using Omu.ValueInjecter;

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass(BaseClass baseObj)
    {
        this.InjectFrom(baseObj);
    }

    public string Abc { get; set; }
    public int Pqr { get; set; }
    public object Xyz { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(BaseClass baseObj, int new1, object new2) : base(baseObj)
    {
        New1 = new1;
        New2 = new2;
    }

    public int New1 { get; set; }
    public object New2 { get; set; }
}
```

The first time you run this code, it will create a mapper and store it in memory so the following times you perform the same operation will be much faster.

If you don't want to use value injecter or any other library, simply set the properties manually in your base class.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass(BaseClass baseObj)
    {
        Abc = baseObj.Abc;
        Pqr = baseObj.Pqr;
        Xyz = baseObj.Xyz;
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're on an older AM version. But if you have an executable gist that shows how the latest version is slow, I want to see it :)

Comment: Actually, I stopped using it 3 or 4 years ago after we had to refactor a large Web application because we were using auto mapper extensively to convert database entities to view models and it was causing major performance problems (yes we had mappings set up and used it as intended, nothing too complex). After replacing it, the problem was solved. Maybe this is no longer the case these days but I cannot recommend it due to my own personal experience, also, ValueInjecter is much simpler to use.

Comment: That's a long, long time ago :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use prototype pattern. If you use C#, Please refer code as below:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;

    public abstract BaseClass Clone();
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int new1;
    public int new2;

    public override BaseClass Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone() as BaseClass;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", a, b, c, new1, new2);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass AClass = new DerivedClass();
        AClass.a = 1;
        AClass.b = 2;
        AClass.c = 3;

        DerivedClass BClass = AClass.Clone() as DerivedClass;
        BClass.new1 = 4;
        BClass.new2 = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(BClass.ToString());
    }
}
```

It comes from https://mobilechos.blogspot.com/2019/04/prototype-pattern-with-csharp.html.